# including a string as a parameter to a function in a header file? c++

Tags: c++

I have this header file, zeeheader.h, and I wrote some classes in it, I'm having problems giving a string as a parameter to one of the functions:

```
class DeliTest
{

public:

    void DeliCheck(Stack*,string);
    void ComCheck (unsigned,string);
    bool EofCheck (unsigned,string);
};
```

As I was implementing it in the cpp file, I added #include to it, it seemed to be working, for example: as I was writing the "data." I got the "length()" appear by the intellisense, so I thought that it was working, but it wasn't. I got errors like:

syntax error : identifier 'string'
overloaded member function not found in 'DeliTest'

this is one of the functions in the cpp file:

```
bool DeliTest::EofCheck(unsigned i, string data)
{

    if (i == data.length()-1)
        return 1;
    return 0;

}
```

Am I supposed to be adding something to the header file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to `#include <string>`, and because `strings` are in the `std` namespace, you should declare your `strings` as `std::string` in the header.

As a sidenote, make sure you do NOT declare `using namespace std;` in your header files.  This would cause any other headers or c/cpp files that include this header to also use the std namespace.  This is called polluting the namespace.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the super fast responses and tips :) problem solved !

Comment: Make sure to click the check mark on the left of the best answer to indicate that the problem has been solved.

Answer (score 7):

In the header file you need:

```
#include <string>
```

strings live in the std:; namespace, so your functions should look like:

```
void DeliCheck(Stack*, std::string);
```

and although it is not wrong to pass strings by value, as you are doing, it is more common and better practice to pass them by const reference:

```
void DeliCheck(Stack*, const std::string & );
```

Comment: @Neil, if I had votes remaining, I'd upvote you. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to use the standard string class? If so you need to add:

`#include <string>`

at the top of your header file. And then also prefix your usage of string with `std::`; e.g.

`void DeliCheck(Stack*, std::string);`

You may also want to name your arguments for clarity, and you probably don't want to pass the strings by value:

`void DeliCheck(Stack* s, const std::string& name);`

Comment: umm should i name the arguments in the header file too? cuz i thought it's enough to name them in the cpp file?

Comment: Naming the arguments is optional in the header file, but it can be useful to provide a description of what the arguments are.

Comment: Nara, consider reading a header file and finding a function like this: `void foo(char*, char*, char*);` Wouldn't you like to see the argument names to give you some idea of how to use the function?

Answer (score 0):

You should `#include <string>` and keep in mind that string is part of the standard library so it is in the std namespace.  You can either add: `using namespace std;` at the top of your header or fully qualify the string class with `std::string` where you use it.  You really should get in the habit of using a fully qualified class name especially in a header file.

Comment: -1 for suggesting adding "using namespace std;" in a *header* file. That can fly in a .cpp source file, but is inappropriate in a header. Damn, my vote limit is exceeded.

Comment: It's not a good idea to put `using namespace xxx;` in a header file.

Comment: I said it was an option.  I guess I should have said it was a bad option.